# Passagem de Dados Flutter

Tags: http, http-request, get, flutter

Tenho um botão que faz uma requisição `get` em um servidor.
A passagem de dados está correta porém na hora que eu tento recuperar na class da build da erro.

```
class Layout_ResultadoExames extends StatefulWidget{

  String Dados;

  Layout_ResultadoExames({this.Dados});

  @override
  _Layout_ResultadoExames createState() => _Layout_ResultadoExames();

}
```

Comment: Postar e detalhar o erro, e principalmente o código onde o erro ocorre.

Comment: Na Class que contem a build eu tento recuperar oque chegou.

Comment: class _Layout_ResultadoExames extends State<Layout_ResultadoExames> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  var Dados = widget.Dados;

}

Comment: Mas aparece esse erro "only static members can be accessed in initializers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve fazer essa atribuição no método [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html):

```
String Dados;
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Dados = widget.Dados;
}
```

Explicação: 
No momento em que você atribuiu o valor à variável `Dados` , isto é, na inicialização da classe, ela ainda não tinha terminado de ser construída e portanto referências ao próprio objeto (this) não podem ser acessadas.

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Sem problemas! Se a resposta está correta e lhe agrada, não esqueça de marcar como correta para melhor indicar quem tiver essa dúvida no futuro.